# C - having trouble with strtok

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I'm trying to load some highscores of a game to this kind of struct:

```
typedef struct{
    char date_time[20];
    int record_minutes;
    int record_seconds;
    int plays;
} Highscore;
```

The highscores are stored in a txt file like so: "nrplays minutes seconds date_and_time"

e.g. `15 2 10 31/12/2017-23:00:20`

The first bit of the code I am using to read the file (which has only 3 lines, that's why I didn't create a loop) is the following

```
void loadHighscores(){

    FILE *f;

    if (check_ifEmptyFile()==-3)
            return;

    f=fopen("highscores.txt", "r");

    char linha[30];
    char *token;

    High1 = (Highscore *)malloc(sizeof(Highscore));

    fgets(linha, 30, f);
    printf("linha: %s", linha);

    token = strtok(linha, " \n");
    High1->plays=atoi(token);
    printf("%d\n", High1->plays);

    token = strtok(NULL, linha);
    High1->record_minutes=atoi(token);
    printf("%d\n", High1->record_minutes);

    token = strtok(NULL, linha);
    High1->record_seconds=atoi(token);
    printf("%d\n", High1->record_seconds);

    token = strtok(NULL, linha);
    snprintf(High1->date_time, 20*sizeof(char), "%s",token);
    printf("%s",High1->date_time);
}
```

The output was this

```
linha: 15 2 10 31/12/2017-23:00:20
15
2
0
/
```

which means strtok isn't doing what I intended it to do. Any tips?

Note that `High1` was defined previously, the `malloc` isn't wrong and also that `High1->date_time` should be the whole 31/12/2017-23:00:20 string.

Comment: Given that the prototype for strtok is `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);` you're not using the function properly: the second parameter should be the delimiters.

Comment: You should probably be using something other than `linha` in `token = strtok(NULL, linha);` — probably `" \n"` if the other occurrences are anything to go by.  Using `strtok()` is hard; avoid it when you can.

Comment: There's nasty interconnectedness in the lines `FILE *f;

    if (check_ifEmptyFile()==-3)
            return;

    f=fopen("highscores.txt", "r");` — to make any sense, `check_ifEmptyFile()` has to know and use the file name `"highscores.txt"` too.  Reduce coupling; pass file names to functions for them to work on.  That applies to the `loadHighScores()` function; it should probably be given the file name to work on.

Comment: thanks guys, didn't pay attention to what I was doing

Answer (score 2):

In `strtok()` the second parameter should be the delimeter.
So, in your case, should be the character space: ' '.

```
token = strtok(linha, " ");
```

and for successive calls:

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

where you parsing every line in `linha`.

Comment: The code in the question uses `" \n"` space-newline; that might be appropriate too.